# On restart mysql flush mysql-relay-bin log files

Tags: mysql

I have mysql replication master-slave of slave i make backups.
I use mysql-relay-bin to restore mysql database on crash. The problem is that in every restart mysql-relay-bin is deleted and create a new.
How to stop the creation of new mysql-relay-bin file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a new log file is created whenever slave I/O thread starts, if your old relay logs get deleted, this means usually that the slave is in sync with master (all events are applied to the slave db). This means your setup works as intended.

If you need persistant log files on the slave, you should activate binary logging on the slave host (as you did on master for replication setup). Also you want the updates which are coming from replication itself, this is archieved using the `log-slave-updates` parameter. Here is an example of the mysqld conf on the slave:

```
expire_logs_days  = 5
log-slave-updates = 1
log_bin           = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

For further information on the parameters refer to [MySQL docs on replication options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html)

Keep also in mind that this will cost you additional disk space and also requires a different backup strategy in order to perform point in time recovery of your db.

Comment: Which log is most appropriate to use a restored information to backup. Mysql-bin on master or mysql-bin, mysql-relay-bin on slave?

Comment: Most of the time I would stick to the binary log of the master, since this information is up to date (imagine a database crash when your replication is not running). E.g. my backups are taken in the following way: Dump of Tables on the Slave after replication is stopped, copying away binlogs on master. In case of recovery i would write back the dump to the master and after this apply the binlogs to it.

Comment: Тhanks for quick reply. How to know to whith point to restore from binary log? Тo not get duplication or loss of ids.

Comment: At this point I want to refer to the MySQL docs on point in time recovery, I think a detailed explanation would be too long for a comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html also a very easy to understand example can be found here: http://www.bytetouch.com/blog/system-administration/mysql-backup-and-point-in-time-recovery-with-binary-logs/

Comment: @user1309635 Welcome to stackoverflow. Please accept an answer (with the green checkmark to the left) when it helped you. Others don't want to waste time reading your question and so on when it's already solved. Thanks.